# How do I have io.sockets.on call an external/global function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, scope, closures

In Node.js, I have the following code which works fine:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8082);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', function (msg) { console.log("message"); console.log(msg); socket.send('Your msg received [[' + msg + ']]');  });
  socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log("disconnect"); });
});
```

...  but what I want to do is to somehow call a function "external" to this:

```
function fnParseMsg(msgArgInFunction)
{
    // do some stuff with the msg...
    console.log("message"); console.log(msgArgInFunction); socket.send('Your msg received [[' + msgArgInFunction + ']]');
};

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8082);
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message', fnParseMsg(msg));
  socket.on('disconnect', function () { console.log("disconnect"); });
});
```

I would imagine I somehow need to use a closure; but I'm unsure as to how...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set a callback you just pass the function, not call it, unless the function you are calling returns a function

```
socket.on('message', fnParseMsg);
```

Also since you want to use the `socket` in the `fnParseMsg` function you need to pass it, you can do this two ways

```
socket.on('message', function(msg){
   fnParseMsg(msg,socket);
});
```

Or use ***[bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)***

```
socket.on('message', fnParseMsg.bind(null,socket));
```

The `bind` call will prepend `socket` to the argument list when the function is invoked. You will need to modify your `fnParseMsg` declaration to have a `socket` parameter

```
//For the first snippet using the anonymous function
function fnParseMsg(msgArgInFunction,socket) {

//For the second snippet using bind
function fnParseMsg(socket,msgArgInFunction) {
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try both methods.  Is there a best-practice?

Comment: Not that i know of, i think it is just what you are comfortable with